# Formatting Microsoft Chart Control X Axis labels for sub-categories to be like charts generated in Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, charts

I am having issues attempting to replicate a chart that has been generated in Microsoft Excel 2007 by using the Microsoft Chart Control for .Net

The chart is showing the TOP 5 entries for each Month (each month could have a different 5 entries) of the year and then showing a breakdown of some metrics

I can get the data perfectly fine, the issue comes down to the fact that in the Excel chart it has formatted the X-Axis labels as shown in the following image:
[image: Microsoft Excel 2007 Chart]
Which is how we want the axis formatted so that each Month name is only listed once for the 5 sub categories that are for that month.

But I do not know how to reproduce this using the Microsoft Chart Control, when I use the same data for the chart control it formats the X-Axis as (ignore colors and such):
[image: Microsoft Chart Control version]
I have bound the data so that the XAxis value is "January AAA-BBB", I'm thinking that maybe I need to separate out the Month portion into some other axis value that can be formatted/grouped separately.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have managed to use a series of CustomLabel's that I manually position to be under the correct "sections".

```
foreach (string monthName in monthNames)
{
    CustomLabel monthLabel = new CustomLabel(startOffset, endOffset, monthName, 1,     LabelMarkStyle.Box);
    theChart.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(monthLabel);
    //increment startOffset and endOffset enough to position the next label
    //under the correct "section"
}
```